# How to use the Stolz-Cesaro to solve $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2 \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n i a_i}{ c - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i}$ + Attempt Edit

Tags: limits, summation

As mentioned, my limit is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2 \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n i a_i}{ c - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i}$$

I know that $0 < c < 1$ and $0 < a_i < 1$ for all $i$, and I also know that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i > c$.

I know there are a few cases about whether or not $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ is convergent or not. I know that the Stolz-Cesaro theorem can be used to solve this but my attempts to understand and apply the theorem have not gone well. Suffice it to say, I'm not sure how even to begin.

Looking for some help not just getting a solution to this problem but also understanding how the solution was achieved.

Thanks all

Edit: I gave this problem another attempt yesterday. I think I'm beginning to understand the Stolz-Cesaro theorem. Apparently it's got the nickname of the Discrete L'Hopital's Rule, so that's cool. I don't know if my attempt is correct though.

Attempt One: The Stolz-Cesaro theorem seems to say

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i+1} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i+1} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i}$$

Given both the limits exist. Not positive if I've got that right, but I think that's what it's saying.

Then applying that to my limit gives

$$ 2 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n (i+1) a_{i+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n i a_i}{ c - (\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i)}$$

I can pull out the last terms on the first sum on the top and the bottom now

$$ 2 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (n+1)a_{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (i+1) a_{i+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n i a_i}{ c - (a_{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_{i+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i)}$$

Now I can rebase those sums

$$ 2 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (n+1)a_{n+1} + \sum_{i=2}^{n} i a_{i} - \sum_{i=1}^n i a_i}{ c - (a_{n+1} + \sum_{i=2}^{n} a_{i} - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i)}$$

Now if I pull out the first terms in the second sum on the top and bottom

$$ 2 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (n+1)a_{n+1} - 1 \cdot a_{1} + \sum_{i=2}^{n} i a_{i} - \sum_{i=2}^n i a_i}{ c - (a_{n+1} - a_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{n} a_{i} - \sum_{i=2}^n a_i)}$$

And now the rest of the sums will cancel.

$$ 2 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (n+1)a_{n+1} - 1 \cdot a_{1}}{ c - (a_{n+1} - a_1)}$$

Now if I clean up a bit, and distribute the parenthesis in the top

$$ 2 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ na_{n+1} + a_{n+1} - a_{1}}{ c - a_{n+1} + a_1}$$

And here, we know that $c$ and $a_{i}$ are all just constants. so we can apply the limit.

$$ 2 \cdot \frac{ \infty \cdot a_{n+1} + a_{n+1} - a_{1}}{ c - a_{n+1} + a_1} \to \infty$$

So the limit becomes infinity. (Which was my original guess, but I feel like I've walked over a lot of different things here. There was no checking convergence or anything. I'm not sure that even matters with how I did it? If there is anyone more expert who's willing to confirm whether I've done it right, I'd sure appreciate some feedback.

Thanks again!